# Follow links returned from PHP array one at a time with a pause

Tags: php, javascript

I have a json_encoded array of links that I'm returning from a php file, what I'm wanting to do is open a new window, have it change the url to each of the links one at a time and pause for about 15 seconds before moving to the next item.

If I use `sleep(15)` in the PHP file, it seems to pause the whole thing then kick the results out all at once.

And using `setTimeout(function () {})` doesn't seem to help either when used in the `for` loop.

There's go to be a way to do it, I'm just not familiar enough I guess.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

So if I'm following correctly...you're suggesting something like

```
$.post('../php/myPHP.php',{ input: input1, value: value } )
      .done(function(r) {
           var results = $.parseJSON(r);

           var display = function() {

           if(results.length > 0) {
           show_url_in_a_new_window(results.link.pop());
           setTimeout(display, 15 * 1000);
           }
        };

        display();

        })
       .fail(function() {
       console.log('Epic Fail!');
});
```

instead of trying

```
for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++) { ... }
```

Right?

--New Edits
I've gotten the window to open, but it just jumps to the last link in the results?!

```
    $.post('../php/myPHP.php',{ input: input, values: Values } )
            .done(function(r) {
                    var results = $.parseJSON(r);

                    function windowOpener(url, name) {
                        if (typeof(popupWin) !== "object"){
                            popupWin = window.open(url, name);
                        } else {
                            if (!popupWin.closed){
                            popupWin.location.href = url;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $('#content').html('');

                    for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++) {
                        console.log(results[i].link);

                        setTimeout( windowOpener(results[i].link, 'Window'), 5000); //Still only goes to the last link
                    }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log('Epic Fail!');
            });
```

So I've still got to be missing something...Anyone?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop, just use settimeout and pop an item out of the array.

```
var items = your-array-from-php;
var display = function() {
    if(items.length > 0) {
        show_url_in_a_new_window(items.pop());
        setTimeout(display, 15 * 1000);
    }
};
display();
```

Comment: in my edits am I following your suggestion correctly, or am I totally off base?

Comment: Yeah looks right, also if you use chrome it's helpful to use the debug console (F12).

Comment: If i helped, maybe you could mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a sleep on the server, that will just delay whatever output from being sent to the client. Instead you should either make repeated calls to the server for a new URL each time, or you should return an entire list of URLs one time and use `setTimeout` to open it. You can use the `window.open` method to manipulate a new window with whichever URL.

Also, posting code would probably be more helpful to you.